# how to include timestamp in log files generated in firebreath

Tags: c#, logging, firebreath

I have successfully generated log files for my project in visual c# generated through firebreath. But I want to include timestamp values in the generated log files. Kindly help me in this regard..

Answer (score 0):

... visual c#? You can't use c# with FireBreath.... Next point is that if you're using log4cplus (and if you think htmlLog counts as logging you've not read the documentation at all and missed the fact that you shouldn't ever use that in production) you get timestamps by default.

See the [Logging](http://www.firebreath.org/x/8IBR) page on firebreath.org for information on how to set this up.  Note that this is the first response in google under "firebreath logging".